# Conditional check for embedded video in the_content

Tags: conditional-tags, oembed

I have a site where single.php displays the post stuff in this order:

- title
- featured image
- the_content

I would like to remove the featured image IF the_content includes an embedded link (f.eg. to a youtube or vimeo video)

I've tried to figure it out by searching the web, but all the solutions i've found are obsolete as they were developed for older versions of wordpress (<4.0).

Is there a way to make it work?